# Hello. First time here. I have a problem regarding an infinite While Loop using C

Tags: c, while-loop

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2wMi.png)

The game is supposed to get integer entries from 1 to any number except multiples of 3 and 7, stopping when the user presses 0. The program has to show how many errors were made at the end.

The problem is that I keep getting prompted to type a number after pressing 0. I would love some help, thanks for reading and sorry for any mistakes.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main () {
    int number, errors;

    errors = 0;

    printf ("Type the next number or 0 to stop: ");
    scanf ("%s", &number);
    fflush (stdin);

    while (number != 0) {
        printf ("Type the next number or 0 to stop: ");
        scanf ("%s", &number);
        fflush (stdin);

        if (number %3 == 0 || number %7 == 0)
        {
            errors = errors + 1;
        }
    }

    printf ("Number of errors: %s", errors);
}
```

Comment: `scanf ("%s", &number);` should be `scanf ("%d", &number);`. Your compiler ought to have warned you about this.

Comment: You are using the wrong "conversion specifier" in scanf: For integer numbers it's `%d`. Same in the printf at the end. Then, also provide a return type for main() (although that's not the error here). A question format remark: If possible, do not post pictures but copy and paste the session text in your question. (But it is good that you posted the error at all ;-).)

Comment: When I looked at this, I pasted it into an editor, saved it, and compiled it with gcc 9.3.0, and it didn't warn about the printf or scanf usage (I believe the MS compiler does warn).  It *did* warn me about main not having a declared return value (which also would've not been a warning in the more distant past).

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues, one of which causes the infinite loop.  In your scanf statements, you appear to have used "%s" where you meant "%d".  If you look at the documentation for scanf, you'll see that "%s" is the conversion specifier for reading a string, so the corresponding argument should be a char*.  "%d" expects the argument to be a pointer to integer, which is what you're passing.  Older compilers generally didn't flag this kind of mismatch between the conversion specifier and the corresponding argument, and C didn't generally care in the past.  At least some contemporary compilers will warn you about this issue.

The other issues are:

1. The printf call should also use "%d".
2. The first value you read before the loop is never checked because when you enter the loop you immediately read another value.
3. The 0 entered by the user that ends the program always result in an increment to the error counter.

These aren't huge, serious errors or anything.  You clearly understood the problem and just made a few errors coding the logic.

Comment: That was the error. I also changed errors = 0; to errors = -1; so that the 0 pressed to end the program didn't count as an error. Thank you.

Comment: Changing the initial value of errors to -1 isn't quite going to work.  If the first thing the user enters is 0, the program will immediately end and report -1 errors.  You need to only read within the loop and restructure a little logic in there so that it does what you intend.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need those fflush(stdin) calls.  They're really not doing anything needed by the program anyway.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)`, in fact, results in undefined behavior.

Comment: True, thanks Christian Gibbons.  Though fflush is defined for seekable input streams, it's behavior on the input end of a pipe or on a terminal appears undefined.